# Storing user progress in php sessions

Tags: php, session

I am creating a website containing quiz with different levels, in which I want to store user progress when he/she logs out.. He should be able to continue from the level which he logged out in. how can I use database to store the current level of user while logout and retrieve level on login?

please suggest some online help or tutorials to get this done. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are bad idea (if he/she is doing test at school/work and gets home, cookies are no longer actual).

Session id is stored in cookies (most of the time) and session variables should be unique for each connection so again not a good option.

Of course cookies and session id can be erased manually (to hide attempts with bad results or wiping out class mates progress).

So only viable option is using the database... There's lot of tutorials on this, please ask any question in comment and I will edit answer.

Here's an [article](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.html) about foreign keys, the [one in mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html) seems to be bit more difficult to read but you should learn how to read those.

Here're [tutorials](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/PHP/Polls-and-Voting/1) on creating polls and vote systems, especially [this one seem](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/How-to-create-a-simple-POLL-system-with-PHP-MySQL-and-Ajax/62395)  good (name, haven't read it).

Comment: As the website will require multiple users logging in from multiple computers, storing progress in database is more viable than cookies.. can u suggest any online tutorials to store sessions in database? thanks for the help

Comment: @prit2192 you don't have to store session into database, you have to store there partial results with user ID. Maybe some table design with correct usage of foreign keys and poll examples would help. Take your time, browse trough provided link and than ask more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are good, but be sure to store some level codes only, not numbers.

Some tutorials: [tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php), [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp), [PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: I don't agree with your answer. Please read mine answer and tell me your counter arguments. (I don't mean to offend, I just think you forgot to think about those specific cases)

Comment: You're right, but I think that in the case that support of more computers isn't required (and mostly it isn't) also as bad results, mine works well. But if it isn't just a "try until you have finished" type quiz, like guess the answer, but a select from four/etc., you're right.

Comment: Cookies unfortunately rely on that user won't spoof (even deleting them may be considered spoofing) them. And he will. :) I would.

Comment: Me too. Your solution works in all the cases but if it isn't a serious money-based/highscore-listed site, then a small cheating isn't that serious. But I like your answer more, it is more sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an ongoing history of quiz results for a user you will want a database. Cookies are fine for storing the progress on a particular quiz but not a reliable way to store a user's history. Also, with cookies the user won't be able to start a quiz on one device and then continue on a second device. For multi-device progress tracking database sessions will be superior.

Comment: can u help me with good database session tutorials that i could refer?

Comment: Here is a good link for using the database for storing sessions: http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database

Comment: However , that alone won't solve your problem. You need to learn about using databases in general for storing user information. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are useful when storing the data during a (single) session, but as I understand you want to be able to restore the previous progress from an old session in a new session. Therefore you will need to store the progress somewhere else, e.g. in a database.

If the session data is only to be saved when the user explicitly logs out you could store the session data when your logout()-method is called and then load it on login(). But this means, that e.g. when the session times out the data from the current session might be lost (!) and therefore is probably not desirable.

Another solution might be to have something like "save points", certain milestones in the quiz where the data is stored in a more permanent storage (e.g. the aforementioned database).